# Find maximums in list

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I want to find local highs in a list. If a vertex consists of several identical maximum values, I want to take the first one and ignore the rest.

```
from scipy.signal import argrelextrema
import numpy as np
data = np.array ([1,2,3,4,4,5,4,3,2,1,0,-1,4,5,6,7,7,7,6,5,4,3])
result = argrelextrema(data, np.greater_equal, order=3)[0]
print (result)

Output:
[ 5 15 16 17]
```

Expected output:

```
[ 5 15]
```

Any other solutions and libraries are possible. It is not necessary to use **scipy**.
High performance solutions are appreciated because my list is 8 trillion values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [find_peaks](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html#scipy.signal.find_peaks)

Returns the middle peak in pleateaus which OP in comments mentioned was also acceptable

```
from scipy.signal import find_peaks
data = np.array ([1,2,3,4,4,5,4,3,2,1,0,-1,4,5,6,7,7,7,6,5,4,3])
result = find_peaks(data)[0]
#result: array([ 5, 16], dtype=int64)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well for my first draft I came up with something like:

```
up = False
tmp_idx = 0
tmp_val = 0
for idx, val in enumerate(a):
    if idx == 0:
        continue
    if a[idx-1] == a[idx]:
        if tmp_val != a[idx - 1]:
            tmp_idx = idx-1
            tmp_val = a[idx-1]
    elif a[idx-1] < a[idx]:
        up = True
    elif a[idx-1] > a[idx] and up:
        if tmp_val == a[idx-1]:
            list.append(tmp_idx)
        else:
            list.append(idx-1)
        up = False
```

> I want to take the first one and ignore the rest.

That part was the trick part.

For the last point, the code can be simplified to:

```
list = []
up = False
tmp_idx = 0
tmp_val = 0
for idx, val in enumerate(a):
    if idx == 0:
        continue
    if a[idx-1] < a[idx]:
        up = True
    elif a[idx-1] > a[idx] and up:
        list.append(idx-1)
        up = False
```

output:

```
[5, 17]
```